# Qgis 2.18 unknown Error when Extract by location

Tags: qgis-processing

I hope somebody can help me.

At first I have merge some vectorlayers (lineshape) without problems. Then I've create a bounding box with "polygon from layer extend" (polygon-shape) without problems too.

And then when I tried to "extract by location", I always get the following error (screenshot).

At first i've thought the reason would be the large nummer of datasets (>3 million), but i get the same error with fewer datasets. Now i THink the problem is because of the merging tool, perhaps. But I can't imagine.[image]

I've attached a screenshot from the error text. Perhaps you can understand it better than me
[image]

Comment: Make sure that both layers that you are using with extract by location have the same projection.

Comment: Yes, they have the same projection

Comment: Try to load both layers into a new QGIS project file and do extract by location, and check if the error occurs.

Comment: This step I've also done.....same problem.

Now i will try to use another version. But I don't think that it will be function

Comment: So it doesn't function too.
Now i have no idea more

Comment: I've attached a screenshot from the error text. I hope somebody can help me;-)